# PostgreSQL JOIN TWO TABLES SYNTAX

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join

I'm trying to find a solution for my problem but hours of thinking and searching didn't help. So I thought maybe i could ask it here.

I have two tables:

```
Table: Project

projectid  | projectName | projectInformation | totalPrice |  projectStatus  
-------------- ------------  -------------------  ----------    -------------
  1          "Education"     "Information..."      2000          FALSE    
  2          "Hospital"      "Information..."      3000          TRUE
  3          "Water"         "Information..."      1000          TRUE


  Table: Donations
  donationid | donationamount | date | costumerid | projectid
  ----------   --------------   ----   ----------   ---------
  1               10            now()   3            1
  2               20            now()   1            2
  3               50            now()   2            2
  4               15            now()   4            3
```

I want to archive the following results:

```
projectid | projectname | projectinformation | totalprice | projectstatus | sum(amount)
1            "Education"     "information..."    2000          FALSE          325
2            "Hospital"      "information..."    3000          TRUE           
3            "Water"         "information..."    1000          TRUE           120
```

So costumers can donate a x amount for a project.

I want to show the collected amount of money for each project. When I do the following query it gives me only the projects with donations only. I want to show all projects as well if there are no donations yet and put as default amount 0 USD for example.

This was my query that gives only project with donations:

```
select projectid, projectname, projectinformation, totalprice, projectstatus, sum(amount) 
from project 
     natural join donation 
group by projectid, projectname, projectinformation, totalprice, projectstatus;
```

I guess I need to use left outer join but somehow I couldn't figure out how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a `left join`:

```
select p.projectid, p.projectname, p.projectinformation, p.totalprice, 
       p.projectstatus, coalesce(sum(d.amount), 0)
from project p left join
     donation d
     on p.project_id = d.project_id
group by p.projectid, p.projectname, p.projectinformation, p.totalprice, p.projectstatus;
```

I strongly discourage you from using `natural join`.  Leaving out the `join` keys makes the query hard to follow and very difficult to debug.  You can easily make mistakes with the wrong keys used for the `join`.

I actually consider `natural join` an abomination, because it depends on the *names* of columns rather than on formally declared foreign key relationships -- "abomination" is my description for ignoring such intentionally declared relationships.  If you want a short-hand, the `using` clause can be quite useful.

Comment: Gordon Linoff my hero :) Thank you very much, i'll take your advice!